# trying to filter content to display multiple selections, but it's not pulling all content from the selected options

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I'm using `type=checkbox` to create a list of filters. Ideally, when 2 or more of the options are selected, I'd like the div's that connect to those selections to be displayed. Currently, it's only displaying 1 (or none, but I can't recreate the issue of the page going completely blank in jsfiddle) of the selected options. It also doesn't reset if nothing is selected.

Is it possible to do this with JavaScript or do I have to download a library?

My HTML

```
    <div id="filter-input-wrapper" class="filter">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="value1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="filter">Value1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="value2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="filter">Value2</label>
    </div>
    <button id="addFilter">Add Filters</button>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <h3 class="card-title">Title1</h3>
    <p class="value1">Info</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h3 class="card-title">Title2</h3>
    <p class="value1">Info</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h3 class="card-title">Title3</h3>
    <p class="value2">Info</p>
</div>
```

My JavaScript

```
let x = document.getElementsByClassName('container')
let addFilter = document.getElementById('addFilter')

addFilter.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="filter"]:checked')
let values = []
    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
        values.push(checkbox.value);
    })

        values.forEach(val => {
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (!x[i].innerHTML.includes(val)) {
          x[i].style.display="none"
        } else {
          x[i].style.display="block"
        }
      }
    })
})
```

*EDIT jsfiddle didn't connect properly so I removed it to add a code snippet directly*

I'm using nodeJS and MongoDb with the Handlebars templates so the `p class="value"` element is where I need to match up with the selection in the checkbox and there are 14 different classes that it could be so ideally, this could be solved with looping and doesn't muddy up the code too much.

```js
let x = document.getElementsByClassName('container')
let addFilter = document.getElementById('addFilter')

addFilter.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="filter"]:checked')
let values = []
    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
        values.push(checkbox.value);
    })

        values.forEach(val => {
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (!x[i].innerHTML.includes(val)) {
          x[i].style.display="none"
        } else {
          x[i].style.display="block"
        }
      }
    })
})
```

```html
   <div id="filter-input-wrapper" class="filter">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="value1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="filter">Value1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="value2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="filter">Value2</label>
    </div>
    <button id="addFilter">Add Filters</button>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <h3 class="card-title">Title1</h3>
    <p class="value1">Info</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h3 class="card-title">Title2</h3>
    <p class="value1">Info</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h3 class="card-title">Title3</h3>
    <p class="value2">Info</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only displaying one filter because when you loop over the checked values to edit the elements, you re-edit all the elements with each loop based on the current/most recent filter.

So if you loop over the elements to check `value1` and show/hide the proper elements, you then loop over **all of them** them again and show/hide based on `value2`, so the first loop's edit are gone.

You can solve this by looping over just the elements, and checking against the values array. To do this, we'll take the `valueX` out of the classlist and into an `data-*` attribute [(1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) that I'll call `data-filter` and add to the container. Then we can use `element.getAttribute()` [(2)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp) to get that value and check against.

```js
let x = document.getElementsByClassName('container')
let addFilter = document.getElementById('addFilter')

addFilter.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="filter"]:checked')
  let values = []
    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
        values.push(checkbox.value);
    })

  for (let element of x) {
    const filter = element.getAttribute('data-filter');
    element.style.display = values.includes(filter)? 'block' : 'none'
  }
   
})
```

```html
<div id="filter-input-wrapper" class="filter">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="value1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="filter">Value1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="value2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="filter">Value2</label>
    </div>
    <button id="addFilter">Add Filters</button>
</div>


<div class="container" data-filter="value1">
    <h3 class="card-title">Title1</h3>
    <p>Info</p>
</div>
<div class="container" data-filter="value1">
    <h3 class="card-title">Title2</h3>
    <p>Info</p>
</div>
<div class="container" data-filter="value2">
    <h3 class="card-title">Title3</h3>
    <p>Info</p>
</div>
```

If you would prefer to use the original class check and looping over the filter values, instead of editing the elements directly, you can add the elements to be shown to an array or `Set` and then loop over the elements and show them if they're in the set and hide if they're not.

```js
let x = document.getElementsByClassName('container')
let addFilter = document.getElementById('addFilter')

addFilter.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="filter"]:checked')
  let values = []
      checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
          values.push(checkbox.value);
      })

  let shownElements = [];

  values.forEach(val => {
    [...x].forEach(element => {
       if (element.innerHTML.includes(val)) {
          shownElements.push(element);
       }
    })
  })
    
  for (let element of x) {
    element.style.display = shownElements.includes(element) ? 'block' : 'none'
  }

})
```

```html
<div id="filter-input-wrapper" class="filter">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="value1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="filter">Value1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="value2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="filter">Value2</label>
    </div>
    <button id="addFilter">Add Filters</button>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <h3 class="card-title">Title1</h3>
    <p class="value1">Info</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h3 class="card-title">Title2</h3>
    <p class="value1">Info</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h3 class="card-title">Title3</h3>
    <p class="value2">Info</p>
</div>
```

Also, there's a couple of different ways you can loop over an `HTML collection` that easier and feel a bit better than using indices. In the snippet above I converted the html collection into an array by spreading `...` it in a new array `[]`, so `[...x]`. You can also use a `for of` loop like the second loop.

Comment: THANK YOU! your first solution looked a lot cleaner but when I tried to implement it, I couldn't get it to work but the second solution worked like magic.. thanks again

Comment: No problem :) When you try the first solution, make sure you add the data-attribute in the div container. `<div class="container" data-filter="value2"></div>`